# Memory Usage Difference b/w Debug and Release Configuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using the `taskInfo` to get the amount of memory my app is using programmatically. The code for that is basically

> ```
>     kern_return_t result = task_info(mach_task_self(), TASK_BASIC_INFO, (task_info_t)&info, &num);
>     if (result == KERN_SUCCESS ) {
>         memoryUsed = (double)(info.resident_size/1000000.0);
> ```

When I run my app on `Debug` configuration it reports far more memory being used as compared to when I run it on `Distribution` (~100MB of difference). Since there are some other third party libraries being linked I'm not sure if they are doing some weird stuff.

My question is assuming that my app is not doing anything weird is it normal to have such a huge difference?

P.S. : I'm also using `cocos2d` but I think that's pretty safe.

Comment: I have observed (measured) the same many times. In fact, i doctored CCDirector to show me FPS and memory, in debug and release mode, just to try to quantify this. As for normality, from my perspective, it has become 'normal' to expect garbage info from xCode and instruments. .02

Comment: In your debug scheme, have you selected any if the memory debugging options (eg zombies)? Those will affect your memory consumption.

Comment: @Rob No I don't, I thought about that first too but I had already stripped down my schemes to have no extra stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it for some more time I've found out that there aren't any issues with cocos2d or any of the other frameworks.

Instead there was a hairy piece of code that was doing something like

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { // a big loop
        [a.b doSomethingAtIndex:i];
    } 
});
```

The object `a` was implemented as proxy object and used `forwardInvocation:` to resolve the message call `a.b` so these invocations were being allocated but never removed since it wasn't surrounded by any `@autorelease pool`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is expected behavior. At least it has always been that way in all projects where I compared memory usage between DEBUG and RELEASE builds.

One reason is obviously in DEBUG builds a lot more things are being done and possibly kept in memory. Debugging stuff mostly, yours and the framework's (ie cocos2d). The various assertions and logs will add more (temporary) memory usage as well. A connected debugger and debugging services may also consume additional memory that is attributed to the app.

There's nothing to be worried about. Measure your memory usage only in release builds because that's what will eventually run on users' devices.

Comment: There is a measurable constant rate of increase in memory consumption, when running with the IDE connected to the running process. However, the same build, when running standalone in the device does not increase in process size over time. So yes, there are the required do-hickies needed to support debug related tasks, but also this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234526/constant-app-memory-increase-ioaccelresource

Answer (score 0):

ARC is sensitive to the optimization settings of the compiler.

The default debug configuration of an app turns off optimization (`-O0`). This causes ARC to be pedantic (redundant?) in the `retain`s and `autorelease`s it inserts which may, in turn, increase the lifetime of objects beyond what one would normally expect.

The default release configuration, on the other hand, has optimization turned on (`-Os`). This causes some `retain`/`release` pairs to be optimized out (I think it also makes less frequent use of `autorelease` as well?) which ends up `dealloc`ing object earlier which means you'll have fewer of them hanging around.

Try this: go to your build settings, and change the "Optimization Level" of the debug configuration under the "Code Generation" section. See if you still see more memory being used after that.

Comment: No this is not the issue I changed the optimization level and it didn't yield any significant change.

Also a difference of 100MB by ARC would mean a large number of objects being created which is not happening. Allocations reveal 30MB of usage which suggests that a difference of more than 100MB via objects is not plausible. It has to be textures I think but I'm not able to pinpoint what.

Also this memory difference is when I reach a steady state in the game when no objects are being created or destroyed so I don't think ARC could cause it.